# For loop that prints from array

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting, substring

I am trying to print out two separate exam marks for students using a text file. 
Below is a screenshot of the text file:

The first column is the student ID and the following two columns are both exam marks

[image]

Below is my code that does that calculations and prints:

```
       //for loop that does calculations and prints
    for(int i = 0; i < arraySize;i++){
        String markOneFull = studentExamOneArray[i];
        String markOneString = markOneFull.substring(5,7);
        double markOne = Double.parseDouble(markOneString);
        examOneNoID[i]= markOne;

        String markTwoFull = studentExamTwoArray[i];
        String markTwoString = markTwoFull.substring(8,10);
        double markTwo = Double.parseDouble(markTwoString);
        examTwoNoID[i] = markTwo;

  /*      String markThreeFull = studentExamThreeArray[i];
        String markThreeString = markThreeFull.substring(5,10);
        double markThree = Double.parseDouble(markThreeString);
        examThreeNoID[i] = markThree;

        String markFourFull = studentExamFourArray[i];
        String markFourString = markFourFull.substring(5,10);
        double markFour = Double.parseDouble(markFourString);
        examFourNoID[i] = markFour;
   */     

        // Aggregate Mark

        double aggregate = (examOneNoID[i] + examTwoNoID[i])/2;
        DecimalFormat oneDigit = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0");


        //time to write
        write.println(studentArray[i] + "\nAB101: " + examOneNoID[i] + " " + " AB102: " + examTwoNoID[i] + " Overall Mark: " + oneDigit.format(aggregate));
        write.println("----------------------------------------");
    }
    write.close();


}
```

When i run the program i get an error message saying:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
  at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
  at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
  at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
  at MarksProcessing.main(MarksProcessing.java:42)
```

Comment: Does your text file end with a newline?

Comment: And is it parsed into `studentExamOneArray` or `studentExamTwoArray`? Resulting in the last element of those arrays being an empty string?

Comment: `markOneFull.substring(5,7)` extracts 2 spaces from the line, just next to the ID including the rest of exam1 value, so it's not valid number?!, so you need to measure the location better, or you can `split()` the values using space(s) and read each line as an array (ID,EXAM1,EXAM2]

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

    int i = 0;
    while (sc.hasNext())
    {
        students[i] = sc.nextInt();
        studentExamOneArray[i] = sc.nextDouble();
        studentExamTwoArray[i] = sc.nextDouble();


        double aggregate = (studentExamOneArray[i] + studentExamTwoArray[i])/2;
        DecimalFormat oneDigit = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0");
        System.out.println("Student: " + students[i] + " FirstGrade: " + studentExamOneArray[i] + " SecondGrade: " + studentExamTwoArray[i] + " Overal: " + oneDigit.format(aggregate));
        i++;
    }
```

Now, you don't need substring and so on. You know the structure of file with grades or whatever that file is. And you don't need extra arrays (you use one for strings and then one for doubles and so on). Just read the numbers into array, then do the math and print.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the specified problem can be easily handled . As we can see that here we are parsing string type into different kind of datatypes , so we should try to catch a Number Format exception.